# Multiple Levels of quotation in php

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and I'm having trouble with multiple levels of nested quotation marks in PHP.

```
echo "<form action=\"readme-p-delete.php?name="<?php echo $result['name']?>"\" method="post">";
```

This is giving me the syntax error, unexpected '?'. Can anyone clarify how I should handle nested quotation?

Comment: You're not escaping all of the quotes in the string and you should concatenate the variable in the string.

Comment: Your `echo` is already in php code. So when you close your " for the first time, it isn't needed to have a new `<?php` tag. Instead use a `.` to glue things together. `echo "<form action=\"readme-p-delete.php?name=" . $result['name'] . "\" method=\"post\">";`

Comment: `echo "<form action=\"readme-p-delete.php?name=" . $result['name'] . "\" method=\"post\">";` returns `<form action="readme-p-delete.php?name=Bob" method="post">`